# Method that does not proceed until event gets fired

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, serial-port

I have a GUI that is linked to several Sensors through COM-Port. I have a Datahandler that makes sure that the received and sent packages have the correct size and content. And then i have a SensorContainer containing all Sensors, firing an event whenever a new sensor is added!

My problem is now: 
I need a method, that can initialize all sensors with one click.

And i just cant do it. If I initialize them one by one, it works, but all in one method doesnt work.
My idea is that the packages get mixed and the handler doesnt accept the sensors anymore for initialization. So i tried to make the method wait for the first sensor to be initialized and the proceed, but i have no clue how! 
I tried a few things with mulitthreading, but im not really experienced in that field and it didnt work out in the end anyway...

**SensorContainerClass**:

```
public static class SensorContainer
    {
        public static event EventHandler<ContainerEvent> ContainerChanged;

        public static ObservableCollection<Sensor> SensorList
        {
            get { return _sensorList; }
        }


        public static void AddSensor(Sensor sensor)
        {
            Sensor sensorExists = GetSensor(sensor.Address);
            if (sensorExists == null)
            {

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _sensorList.Add(sensor));
                ContainerChanged(null,new ContainerEvent(sensor.Address, true));

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's not possible to add multiple sensors with the same address.");
            }
        }
        public static void RemoveSensor(Sensor sensor)
        {
            Sensor sensorExists = GetSensor(sensor.Address);
            if (sensorExists != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _sensorList.Remove(sensor));
                ContainerChanged(null, new ContainerEvent(sensor.Address, false));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No sensor with address " + sensor.Address);
            }
        }

        public static Sensor GetSensor(byte address)
        {
            foreach (Sensor sensor in _sensorList)
            {
                if (sensor.Address == address)
                {
                    return sensor;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        // members
        private static readonly ObservableCollection<Sensor> _sensorList = new ObservableCollection<Sensor>();

    }
```

**DataHandler**:

```
public class DataHandler:ModelBase
    {
        private const int MAX_TIMER_TIME = 500;
        public long answertime_milli;
        Timer aTimer;
        Stopwatch watch;


        Sensor tempSensor;

        private byte[] tempFrame;
        private bool framePartPendingFlag = false;
        public bool framesEqual;
        public bool initalisationFlag = false;
        public InitType initialisationType;


        public byte[] TxFrame
        {
            get { return txFrame; }
        }

        public byte TxAddress
        {
            get { return TxFrame[0]; }
        }

        public byte TxLength
        {
            get { return TxFrame[1]; }
        }

        public byte TxCommand
        {
            get { return TxFrame[2]; }
        }

        public byte[] TxData
        {
            get { return TxFrame.GetRange(3, TxLength - 2); }
        }

        public byte TxChecksum
        {
            get { return TxFrame[TxLength - 1]; }
        }

        private byte[] txFrame;

        private bool successfull;
        public bool Successfull
        {
            get
            {
                return successfull;
            }
            set
            {
                if(successfull != value)
                {
                    successfull = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public DataHandler()
        {
            txFrame = new byte[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            aTimer = new Timer(MAX_TIMER_TIME);
            watch = new Stopwatch();
            CommandManager.Instance.Init();
            InterfaceWrapper.Instance.SerialPort.DataReceived += OnSerialPortReceived;
        }

        public void InitializeSensor(InitType type, byte address, Int32 serialNumber = 0)
        {
            if (SensorContainer.GetSensor(address) != null )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sensoraddress already used");
                return;
            }

            foreach(Sensor temp in SensorContainer.SensorList)
            {
                if(temp.Serialnr == serialNumber)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sensor with the same SerialNumber already initalized");
                    return;
                }
            }

            byte[] frame;

            if (type == InitType.INIT_TO_ONE_DEVICE)
            {
                Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_ONE_TX initStruct = new Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_ONE_TX();
                initStruct.Address = address;
                frame = createFrame(initStruct, 0xFF, 0x20);
            }
            else
            {
                Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_TO_SN_TX initStruct = new Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_TO_SN_TX();
                initStruct.Address = address;
                if (serialNumber == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Serialnumber is missing");
                    return;
                }
                initStruct.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
                frame = createFrame(initStruct, 0x00, 0x22);
            }

            setTxFrame(frame);
            InterfaceWrapper.Instance.SerialPort.SendData(frame);
            initalisationFlag = true;
            initialisationType = type;
        }

        public void StartDataTransfer(Sensor sensor, byte commandid)
        {
            if (sensor == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No such sensor");
                return;
            }

            Command command = sensor.getCommand(commandid);

            if (command == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Command does not exist");
                return;
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<CommandAttribute, Command> pair in sensor.CommandList)
            {
                if (pair.Value == command)
                {
                    timeout = pair.Key.Timeout;
                    transmission = pair.Key.Transmission;
                    break;
                }
            }
            tempSensor = sensor;

            if (SensorContainer.GetSensor(sensor.Address) != null)
            {
                byte[] endFrame = createFrame(command, sensor.Address, commandid);

                setTxFrame(endFrame);
                if (true)
                {
                    InterfaceWrapper.Instance.SerialPort.SendData(txFrame);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sensor not yet initialized");
            }
        }

        private byte[] createFrame(Command command, byte address, byte commandId)
        {
            byte[] data = MarshalHelper.Serialize(command);
            byte[] frame = new byte[4 + data.Length];
            frame[0] = address;
            frame[1] = (byte)frame.Length;
            frame[2] = commandId;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, frame, 3, data.Length);
            frame[frame.Length - 1] = GenerateChecksum(frame);
            return frame;
        }

        public void OnSerialPortReceived(object sender, ComDataRxEvent e)
        {

                byte[] data = e.Data;
                setRxFrame(data);

        }

        public void setTxFrame(byte[] _txFrame)
        {
            Successfull = false;
            txFrame = _txFrame;
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = false;
            aTimer.Start();
            watch.Start();
        }

        public void setRxFrame(byte[] _rxFrame)
        {
            if (framePartPendingFlag)
            {
                byte[] newTempFrame = new byte[tempFrame.Length + _rxFrame.Length];
                tempFrame.CopyTo(newTempFrame, 0);
                _rxFrame.CopyTo(newTempFrame, tempFrame.Length);
                framePartPendingFlag = false;
                setRxFrame(newTempFrame);
            }
            else if (!checkMinLength(_rxFrame))
            {
                tempFrame = _rxFrame;
                framePartPendingFlag = true;
            }
            else if (!checkBit(_rxFrame))
            {
                tempFrame = _rxFrame;
                framePartPendingFlag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                framePartPendingFlag = false;
                aTimer.Stop();
                watch.Stop();
                answertime_milli = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                if (!initalisationFlag)
                {
                    if (checkAll(_rxFrame))
                    {
                        writeCommandToSensor(_rxFrame);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    createSensorAfterInitialization(_rxFrame);
                }
            }
        }


        private void writeCommandToSensor(byte[] frame)
        {
            Command expCommand = CommandManager.Instance.GetRxCommand(tempSensor.GetType(), TxCommand);
            Command command = MarshalHelper.Deserialize(expCommand, frame.GetRange(3, frame[1] - 2));
            tempSensor.setCommand(command);
        }
        private void createSensorAfterInitialization(byte[] frame)
        {
            if (initalisationFlag && initialisationType == InitType.INIT_TO_ONE_DEVICE)
            {
                Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_ONE_RX expCommand = new Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_ONE_RX();
                Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_ONE_RX command = (Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_ONE_RX)MarshalHelper.Deserialize(expCommand, frame.GetRange(3, frame[1] - 2));
                Sensor tempSensor = Sensor.GetSensorInstance(command.SerialNumber, command.Address, command.SensorName, command.SensorSubName, command.dataStructType, command.dataStructSubType,command.pcbVersion,command.firmware);
                tempSensor.setCommand(command);
                SensorContainer.AddSensor(tempSensor);
                initalisationFlag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_TO_SN_RX expCommand = new Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_TO_SN_RX();
                Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_TO_SN_RX command = (Sensor.COM_ADDR_SET_TO_SN_RX)MarshalHelper.Deserialize(expCommand, frame.GetRange(3, frame[1] - 2));
                if (command == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sensor not answering");
                }
                else {
                    Sensor tempSensor = Sensor.GetSensorInstance(command.SerialNumber, command.Address, command.SensorName, command.SensorSubName, command.dataStructType, command.dataStructSubType, command.pcbVersion, command.firmware);
                    tempSensor.setCommand(command);
                    SensorContainer.AddSensor(tempSensor);
                    initalisationFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }


        public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            framePartPendingFlag = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the difference between "initialization one by one" and "all in one method"?

Comment: does the former mean to use a for loop and call `InitializeSensor` each time? and does the latter mean to call `InitializeSensor` in parallel and initialize them simultaneously?